# Как в Unity3D управлять частицами напрямую?

Tags: unity3d

У меня в игре есть очень много одинаковых простых объектов, которые влияют на геймплей. Если их делать `GameObject`'ами, то FPS падает, особенно при их создании, даже с использованием пула. Такое лучше сделать на частицах.

Система частиц в юнити может рендерить частицы очень быстро, но она еще и сама управляет ими: создает, меняет и удаляет. В моем случае эти действия делает игровая логика, а система частиц только мешает.

Я могу задать частицам параметры через метод `SetParticles` и даже удалить частицы, задавая отрицательное время жизни, но почему-то не могу создать, и еще это не мешает системе частиц конфликтовать с моей логикой.

**Что нужно сделать, чтобы выключить у системы частиц ее собственное управление частицами и правильно настроить прямое управление из скрипта?**

[Оригинал вопроса на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55726303/10666424)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После того как мы создали систему частиц в редакторе, нужно выключить **Emission** и **Shape**. Активными должны остаться только основная часть и рендерер.

Самое важное - **Simulation Speed** должно быть 0. Тогда система частиц не будет автоматически испускать, убирать и изменять частицы. Теперь только ваш скрипт будет это делать.

Вот класс, который управляет частицами. Здесь есть API для регистрации объектов, в данном случае дыма. Также тут есть временный массив частиц, чтобы не создавать мусор при вызове `GetParticles`, и количество частиц, чтобы не дергать свойство `particleCount` у системы частиц.

В методе `Update`, вызываемом игровой логикой, происходит следующее:

- Из списка удаляются все объекты с флагом `Despawned` - удаленные из игры.
- Если число объектов больше длины массива, мы его увеличиваем.
- Если объектов больше чем сейчас частиц, вызывается `_particleSystem.Emit`. Если вызвать `SetParticles` без этого, то новые частицы не появятся. Их надо явно создать.
- Вызывается `GetParticles`. Возможно, не самое эффективное решение, но оно сохраняет параметры частиц. Если нужно задавать *вообще все* параметры частиц, нужно задавать начальные параметры при создании и увеличении размера массива частиц и более аккуратно писать игровую логику. Тогда уберите вызов `GetParticles` и раскомментируйте строчку над ним.
- Передаем каждому объекту частицу, чтобы он ее изменил.
- Оставшиеся частицы не имеют своего объекта, мы задаем им отрицательное время жизни, чтобы удалить.
- Частицы в системе обновляются через `SetParticles`

```
    public class SmokeSystem {

        private ParticleSystem             _particleSystem;
        private List <Smoke>               _smoke     = new List <Smoke> ();
        private ParticleSystem.Particle [] _particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[256];
        private int                        _particleCount;


        public SmokeSystem (ParticleSystem particleSystem) {
            _particleSystem = particleSystem;
        }


        public void AddSmoke (Smoke smoke) => _smoke.Add (smoke);


        public void Update () {
            _smoke.RemoveAll (e => e.Despawned);

            if (_smoke.Count > _particles.Length) {
                int newSize = Max (_smoke.Count, 2 * _particles.Length);
                Array.Resize (ref _particles, newSize);
            }

            int count = _smoke.Count;
            if (count > _particleCount) {
                _particleSystem.Emit (count - _particleCount);
                // _particleCount = count;
            }
            _particleCount = _particleSystem.GetParticles (_particles);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                _smoke [i].UpdateParticle (ref _particles [i]);
            }
            for (int i = count; i < _particleCount; i++) {
                _particles [i].remainingLifetime = -1;
            }
            _particleSystem.SetParticles (_particles, _particleCount);
            _particleCount = count;
        }

    }
```

---

Перевод [ответа zambari на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55726871/10666424) (примечание - на WebGL не работает - InvalidOperationException: Instancing is not supported):

Возможно, вам подойдет такой способ:

```
List<Matrix4x4> matrixes=new List<Matrix4x4>();
for (...)
{
    matrixes.Add(Matrix4x4.TRS( position,rotation,scale));
}
Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced(mesh,0,material, matrixes);
```

Вы обновляете позиции, повороты и масштабы объектов, и они все рендерятся за один draw call (намного быстрее чем отдельные GameObject'ы). Таким образом можно вывести до 1000 штук за один вызов.

Comment: Поправочка: не до 1000 мешей, а до 1023 мешей за раз*